# Rest Method throwing exception when static

Tags: java, rest, httpclient

I am trying to RestApi call , The below code i had worked before it wasn't a static method and now that it is a static method it is throwing this exception below: When it is in the same class, it works.

> Cause:java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
>   DetailMessage: Remote host closed connection during handshake

```
public static void getMethod(String pass,String query,String url)throws Exception{

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
           AuthScope.ANY,
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("fzs", pass));
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).setProxy(new HttpHost("proxyName",80))
            .build();

    try {

        String encode = url + (URLEncoder.encode(query,"UTF-8"));

        HttpUriRequest httpget = new HttpGet(encode);


        System.out.println("Executings request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
       try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String message = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            System.out.println(message);

        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
```

Working code:

```
@Test   
    public void RestAPI() throws Exception {


        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
               AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("fzs", pass));
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).setProxy(new HttpHost("proxyName",80))
                .build();

        try {

            String query = "active=true^state!=3^u_entity=u_case^GOTOnumber=CASE0014474";
            String url = "https://service-now.com/api/now/table/u_case?sysparm_query=";



            String encode = url + (URLEncoder.encode(query,"UTF-8"));

            HttpUriRequest httpget = new HttpGet(encode);


            System.out.println("Executings request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
       //     ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
        //    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
           try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
               // System.out.println(responseBody);

            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The fact that it is `static` has absolutely no relation to that exception being thrown.

Comment: When I have as Junit @Test , the exact same code it passes.

Comment: You're not showing us something.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? The client or the server?

Comment: CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); This line throws it

Comment: The following line is not in the static version: 
url = "https://service-now.com/api/now/table/u_case?sysparm_query=";
Can you explain the difference in this regard?
Put another way - what is the precise 'query' and 'url' parameters that are being passed to the non-static variant

Comment: It's the same line, just passed as parameters. It is just querying the api for a specific record. When it is in the same class, it works. When it isn't, it throws that exception.

Comment: When you say "it passes" ... you are catching Exception and not making any assertions, so I would expect that unit test to "pass"  (although I'd assume you'd still see the error message printed to standard out).  So please confirm that you are in fact still seeing the error message, not relying on the test running "green."